# Not writing to csv correctly

Tags: python, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing to a csv file.  It displays correctly in console, however when I open the csv file it is not displayed the Href correctly.

The rest of the job is working fine this is the only issue. 
Code:

```
elems = driver.current_url

for elem in elems:
    print(elems)

print(("NEW LINE BREAK"))
import sys
import io


with open('vtg121.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs_text, langs1_text, langs2_text, langs3_text, elems):
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Your issue is: for elem in elems:
    print(elems)

Comment: You don't ya get the HREF with get.attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably want url to come in each row? If yes then you need to do it this way

```
url = driver.current_url

print(("NEW LINE BREAK"))
import sys
import io


with open('vtg121.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs_text, langs1_text, langs2_text, langs3_text):
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row + (url,))
```

Comment: I seem to be getting: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple for writer.writerow(row + [url])

Comment: Try (url, ) instead of [url]